# GitHub account to r studio

Tags: github, rstudio

this is my first attempt at link my GitHub account to r studio an it gives me this error msg

```
>>> C:/Program Files/Git/bin/git.exe commit -F C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpoXbcuD/git-commit-message-42c06d1722c8.txt
```

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

```
fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'User@DESKTOP-QNBSIRJ.(none)')
```

I read other similar question and tried other solution but it doesn't work for me